# Is there a way to get the browser console output without using the console?

Tags: javascript, browser, console

I'm in a unique situation where my production code is being used does not allow for the browser debugger to open. So bringing up the browser console is not an option. This causes issues when it comes to debugging and finding out what errors come up.

Is there a way to get the console output (errors and warnings) through JavaScript, a library, or API?

I've looked into console API but so far it looks like just different ways to display data within the console.

Comment: Erhm... Move the code to a development environment where you can use the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for all web browsers, but I just tested this on the browser I am using right now, Edge.

What you can do is you can set console.log to a custom function, like (You should backup the standard console.log before calling this)

```
console.log = function (data) {
  alert(data);
}
```

or

```
var logBackup = console.log;
console.log = function(str) {
  // do you analysis/processing on str
  analytics(str);
  // then call the old log
  logBackup(str);
});
```

In your custom (JavaScript) function, you can analyze the output to the log

Answer (score -1):

Try this
Run this command in cmd or powershell

`node inspect file_name.js`

You can debug in console . But node js must be installed in your system.